# On a django form, how do I loop through individual options per field?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm building a form wizard. On the first step I have a form with one field. That field is a foreign key. Django's default widget for a foreign key gives me the field's options in a drop down (select) menu and represenets each option as an html option. I changed the default widget to a RadioSelect. So now it gives me the field's options via radio buttons.

Here is my forms.py

```
class ChooseProductTypeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        widgets = {
            'type': RadioSelect,
        }
```

What I would like to do is be able to loop through each option and get specific data for each option that I store on the model.

I was hoping it would be as simple as:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% for option in field %}
        {{ option.image }}
        {{ option.title }}
        {{ option.description }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

After researching for a day and a half I've decided to see what the community has to say. FWIW, I've found some solutions that would work but are very complicated. There must be an easier way, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can access the choices queryset, but note that a template is probably not the right place for this kind of logic. NB the `field.field` which isn't a typo

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% for option in field.field.choices.queryset %}
        {{ option.image }}
        {{ option.title }}
        {{ option.description }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This does answer the question and you're right; the template is not the place for that logic. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but fields aren't iterable in the way that you're hoping they would be. The thing that you're trying to iterate isn't a queryset; it's a `ModelChoiceField`. You can access the individual choices, but they're represented internally as two-tuples with the ID of the foreign key as the first element, and the `__unicode__` representation as the second element.

As you said, though, there are ways to handle this problem. The best way, even though it's a bit ugly, is probably to send down a dictionary with the information you need using the model IDs as keys. You can use a [values queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#values) to do this quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

I can see this being done in two ways.

You could create a custom widget for this field that would render each options model attributes. This is very possible, but I don't have time right now to write it all out.

Another, quicker method is adding a function in your form that handles this, and returns the data you want

```
class ChooseProductTypeForm(ModelForm):
    def get_my_modelfield(self):
        for option in self.fields['my_modelfield'].queryset:
            yield {
              'image': option.image, 
              'title': option.title, 
              'description': option.description
           }
```

This mostly keeps the database out of the template and simply uses an easy-to-follow form function to return the data you need. If the formfield ever changes, you're no longer scattering adjusting templates, rather just updating this function.

The downside to this is that you can't simply loop through the fields in your form, you'd have to output each one explicitly. Of course, you could also play with `__iter__` on your form but that may be getting too hacky. Not sure what you're dealing with here entirely :)