# Displaying custom checkboxes with Django and ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble wiring my checkboxes together with the template to make a good user experience. I'm sending my form to the view which contains the following MyType which is described as:

models

```
class A(models.Model):
   MyType          = models.ManyToManyField(P)
```

forms

```
MyType    = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=P.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

and the view is being sent as:

return render(request, "static/about.html", {'form': form})

and in the template, I have the following kind of structure

```
 <li class="option table">
 <div class="cell" id="center">
 <div class="option-text">Option 1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="cell" id="right">
 <div class="option-checkbox">
 <div class="check"></div>
 <input id="myid1" name="myname1" value="1" type="checkbox">
 </div>
 </div>
```

Now I can use answer: [On a django form, how do I loop through individual options per field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106311/on-a-django-form-how-do-i-loop-through-individual-options-per-field?rq=1) to loop through, but this only gives the description. How do I recreate the actual HTML that deals with the  options in the smartest way?

I've tried the shell to look at the objects, but I really don't see what I should be pulling in. i.e. in the template to recreate. What fields of each option should I pull in? or how do I get at the right info to build up my HTML such that the saving aspect of the form will work.

In a template I cannot do:

```
{% for field in form["MySmoking"] %}

{% endfor %}
```

so how could I modify the following:

```
 {% for option in form.MyType.field.choices.queryset %}
        {{ option.image }}
        {{ option.title }}
        {{ option.description }}
    {% endfor %}
```

so, how would I spit out the HTML that builds the checkbox.

Thanks.

Comment: `CheckboxSelectMultiple` renders the whole list of checkboxes itself, so to change that you should write a custom subclass of it with a different `render` method. Looking at the code for the existing widget class should get you started.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Is there no shortcut? I.e. anyway to put out enough of the labels in the view - or is this barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I guess it depends on whether you consider writing the loop and outputting all the checkbox HTML yourself in the template to be a shortcut over writing a custom widget. You don't have to render the field using the widget, but if you don't you have to make sure you do everything the widget usually does.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper, if I write a custom widget will I still be able to loop through it in the template? I'll need to write some kind of irritable object??

Comment: What I am recommending is that your subclass widget should output exactly the HTML you want from its `render` function, so that you do not have to loop through it in the template. See the source for the regular widget for an example of how it builds the list of checkboxes: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/forms/widgets.py#L754 (Linked to 1.5 because the development branch exposes the ability to iterate over the checkboxes, which is kind of what you want but not available in a stable release yet.)

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper, Thanks. I shall look at creating my own class based on that. Would you advise - i.e. just copy and paste the class before modifying or try and inherit?

Comment: I'd just inherit from the built in widget, maybe copying and pasting in its `render` method since you're going to come out with something very similar to that method in the end.

Comment: I tried copying the class over as a first start. I've brought in all the classes, but cannot see what package CheckboxInput belongs to i.e. in line: cb = CheckboxInput(final_attrs, check_test=lambda value: value in str_values)

Comment: It's in `widgets`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/forms/widgets.py#L505